# Running a service in the background withouth getting stuck

Tags: process, salt-stack, nohup

Currently I am having an issue with trying to run a process/script in the background[The master starts it on the minion]

The script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup ping 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null&
```

And I call it from the master with:

```
Process-Name:
  service.running:
   - name: Script-Name
   - enable: True
```

For some reason it gets stuck on the master,I've read a little bit on this issue[it has happenned before apparently] and tried their solutions on it but apparently nothing involving the `service state` seems to work.

Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: The question should be clarified. **(1)** If you want to run script in background, your script is **already** able to do so. **(2)** If you want to run your script as a service, you should normally make sure it is **configured** as such (SysV init.d, systemd, ... depends on OS) **and** **implemented** as such (to avoid running more than one instance, to be able to be started and stopped, to serve anything ~ at least logs). **(3)** How to use Salt with what you already created depends on whether it is **(1)** or **(2)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you should configure your script as system daemon *first* (SysV init.d script, or systemd unit, or ... depends on OS).

### Details

The [`service.running`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html#salt.states.service.running) function requires properly configured system service ~ daemon.

For example, on RHEL-based Linux, if you don't see your script name in the output of one of these commands, you should configure it as proper service first (which is [a separate topic](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=shell%20script%20as%20system%20service%20daemon)):

```
# systemd
systemctl list-units | grep your_service_name

# SysV init.d
chkconfig --list     | grep your_service_name
```

And because you want to start it in background, [`cmd.run`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) function is not the right tool either:

- It will only report successful start of the script without waiting for its completion results.
- It will also start new instance of your script every time.

However, if all you simply want is to *"fire and forget"*, use `cmd.run`.